# use dynamic int variable inside regex pattern python

Tags: python, regex, variables, int

I'm in my initial days of learning python, sorry if this question is already been asked.

I'm writing here as those didn't help me, my requirement is reading a file and printing all the URL's inside in it.Inside a for loop the regex pattern i had used is `[^https://][\w\W]*`, it worked fine. But I wanted to know if can I dynamically pass the length of line which is after https:// and get the output with occurrences instead of `*`

I had tried `[^https://][\w\W]{var}}` where `var=len(line)-len(https://)`

These are some other patterns I had tried like

```
pattern = '[^https://][\w\W]{'+str(int(var))+'}'

pattern = r'[^https://][\w\W]{{}}'.format(var)

pattern = r'[^https://][\w\W]{%s}'%var
```

Comment: Right now your pattern is very strange. For example, do you realize that `[^https://]` does not match a string `https://` at the start of the line? Instead it matches any single character, which is not one of h, t, p, s, :, or /.

Comment: yes i realized now  about my https pattern, thanks for finding it out

Comment: @JACK, did any of the provided answers help you, if so please make remember to mark the answer so that others might benefit from that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but if you know that the url is always starting with `https://` then that would be the first eight characters. Then you can get the length after finding the urls:

```
# Example of list containing urls - you should fill that with your for loop
list_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006253/use-dynamic-int-variable-inside-regex-pattern-python', 'https://google.com', 'https://stackoverflow.com']
for url in list_urls:
    print(url[8:])
```

Out

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/61006253/use-dynamic-int-variable-inside-regex-pattern-python
google.com
stackoverflow.com
```

Instead of a for loop you could find all urls using `re.findall`

```
import re

url_pattern = "((https:\/\/)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+[.+]+([\w%\/~\+#]*))"
# text referes to your document, that should be read before this
urls = re.findall(url_pattern, text)

# Using list comprehensions
# Get the unique urls by using set
# Only get text after https:// using [8:]
# Only parse the first element of the group that is returned by re.findall using [0]
unique_urls = list(set([x[0][8:] for x in urls]))

# print the urls
print(unique_urls)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern you use `[^https://]` which is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^` which will match any char except the listed.

One option is to make use of literal string interpolation. Assuming your links do not contain spaces, you could use `\S` instead of `[\w\W]` as the latter variant will match any character including spaces and newlines.

```
\bhttps://\S{{{var}}}(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FkKumA/1)

The assertion `(?!\S)` at the end is a whitespace boundary to prevent partial matches and the word boundary `\b` will prevent http being part of a larger word.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/6fQFMQ)

For example

```
import re
line = "https://www.test.com"
lines = "https://www.test.com https://thisisatestt https://www.dontmatchme"

var=len(line)-len('https://')
pattern = rf"\bhttps://\S{{{var}}}(?!\S)"

print(re.findall(pattern, lines))
```

Output

```
['https://www.test.com', 'https://thisisatestt']
```